# C++ Private Default Constructor with Empty Body

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I saw some code [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/102-composition/).

There is a class with a private default constructor with empty body and a parameterized constructor.
Code comments say that the default constructor was made private "so that it would *not* be possible to create objects with no properties specified" [properties are represented by class data members]. Thus there is no use in explicitly defining a private default constructor because it cannot be utilized!

Once we declared a parameterized constructor a default constructor will not be implicitly supplied by the compiler! Thus there will be no way to create objects with no arguments passed to nonexistent constructor.

My question is why do we need to declare a default constructor in this case *at all*?

Comment: That is true, but what if some time later, *Jimmy* tries to add default constructor because it seems to him a convenience? In other words: the original developer makes it clear that default constructor must never exist.

Comment: Another reason to make it user-declared and private is to get a more specific error message if the user tries to invoke the default-constructor. As opposed to the compiler describing other constructors that were candidates to the call. In C++11 you can simply define it as deleted.

Comment: Though I think both cases would just result in code noise. You can't shield your code from wrong modifications of other developers. If they can access it they might break it. No amount of comments etc. will avoid that in the long run. Aside from comments becoming out of touch with the code they refer to. It could also be that after some refactoring a default constructor makes sense.

Comment: @mat69, indeed, you can't. But what you can is reduce probability of such ignorance.

Comment: In C++11 it would be better to declare the default constructor as deleted (and public not private), as that's a more explicit way of saying "this is intentionally disabled"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are completely correct.
As soon as there is a custom constructor no default constructor will be created.

So you don't need to declare a default constructor in this case.

Also see **§ 12.1 / 5**

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. If there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared
>   as defaulted (8.4). [...]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, author of that is incorrect on how the default constructors work. He may have confuse it with copy constructor which is created automatically even in his case.

Comment: I read the link and I thinks it is not fair to call it "incorrect". For sure it can be misleading, because one doesnt have to write the private constructor in such a case. However, as pointed out in other comments already, writing the private default constructor can be used to make it more explicit that there is no default constructor on purpose.